# Insert a widget over another widget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a Label with an image (pixmap) how can I insert buttons over it? One method I could probably use is to remove the layout and do it by hand (it's currently on **Lay Out Vertically**), however it would be difficult then to "keep it neat", how can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to place one widget over another in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295900/how-to-place-one-widget-over-another-in-qt)

Comment: Does right clicking on the button (in `Design` mode), and pressing `Send to Back` or `Bring to Front` solve your problem?

Comment: @Farshid616 Thanks for the reply but no, it didn't help!

Comment: @joaopedro Thank you too for the reply but that doesn't solve my problem either.